# Translate SQL query to JPQL

Tags: mysql, jpql

Following query:

```
SELECT kinder.kindID, kinder.kindName, kinder.kindVorname 
FROM kinder
INNER JOIN (SELECT kindName FROM kinder
    GROUP BY kindName HAVING count(kindID) > 1) dup ON kinder.kindName = dup.kindName
ORDER BY kindName
```

finds and displays duplicate candidates from my MySQL DB.
Now i need help translating it to JPQL, no sucess so far.

Comment: Do you have to use JPQL? i.e. native SQL is not an option?

Comment: I´m afraid it´s not. The query needs to be executed from within a Java application that needs to be operable on any DBMS. So, no native SQL.

Comment: SQL is pretty standard, at least for what is needed by this query. I'd guess that this query works on any DBMS.

Comment: Yes, I don't see far-from-standard SQL in your query either...

Comment: I gave up myself, can´t get the JPQL right. I used the native Query above. However, should a JPQL wizard stumble upon this, please don´t hesitate to answer the question :)

Answer (score 1):

I've just been experimenting, came up with the same solution as JB. This runs in OpenJPA on WebSphere.

```
    SELECT k.id, k.name, k.vorname from Kinder k where 
        k.name IN (
        SELECT dup.name FROM Kinder dup 
             GROUP BY dup.name  HAVING count(dup.id) > 1)
```

Comment: Is it the same solution JB had posted ? It didn´t compile on Eclipse, although i thought it looked quite correct. I sticked to native SQL at the end. It´s the only native SQL query in a project with about 50-60 JPQL queries, but it does the job. However, it itches me to try it again. I´ll keep the thread posted if it works.

Comment: Usually, one uses `COUNT(DISTINCT dup.id)`. `COUNT(dup.id)` is equivalent to `COUNT(*)` (unless `dup.id` can have NULLs)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where subqueries are allowed in JPQL but your query:

```
SELECT kinder.kindID, kinder.kindName, kinder.kindVorname 
FROM kinder
  INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT kindName
      FROM kinder
      GROUP BY kindName
      HAVING count(kindID) > 1
    ) dup
    ON kinder.kindName = dup.kindName
ORDER BY kinder.kindName
```

can also be written (besides the `IN` way) using `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT k.kindID, k.kindName, k.kindVorname 
FROM kinder k
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM kinder k2
        WHERE k2.kindName = k.kindName
          AND k2.kindID <> k.kindID
      ) 
ORDER BY k.kindName
```

or using `ANY` :

```
SELECT k.kindID, k.kindName, k.kindVorname 
FROM kinder k
WHERE k.kindID <> ANY
      ( SELECT k2.kindID
        FROM kinder k2
        WHERE k2.kindName = k.kindName
      ) 
ORDER BY k.kindName
```

Comment: I´ll try these out Monday morning. Thanks.